# How to write a function to matches values in two dataframes (make a faster version)

Tags: r, performance

I have a dataframe with coordinates of regions of interest, and another dataframe with temperature readings (bio1) taken in research stations, and their coordinates.

I'd like to create a new column to match the region of interest with the temperature of the **nearest** research station.

I have managed to do this with the following code (here's a simplified fake dataframe pair)

```
df1 <- data.frame(latitude = c(10.5,6,2), longitude = c(18,9,4))
df2 <- data.frame(vy = c(10,5,3), vx = c(20,10,3), bio1 = c('a','b','c'))


for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  df1$temperature[i] <- df2$bio1[which(abs(df2$vx - df1$longitude[i]) +
                                             abs(df2$vy - df1$latitude[i]) == 
                                             min(abs(df2$vx - df1$longitude[i]) + 
                                                   abs(df2$vy - df1$latitude[i])))]

}
```

So, this code checks all the combinations and choses the one with the smallest distance between latitude and longitude at each row.

I checked and it seems to work, but it's very slow to use on large dataframes.

Can you solve this issue with a faster method?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
# put some id's in df1
df1$id <- LETTERS[1:3]
# make df1 and df2 simple objects
sf1 <- df1 %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)
sf2 <- df2 %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("vy", "vx"), crs = 4326)
# find nearest sf2 in sf1
sf1 %>%
  mutate(nearest_bio = sf2$bio1[st_nearest_feature(sf2)])

# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 2 fields
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 4 ymin: 2 xmax: 18 ymax: 10.5
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#   id        geometry nearest_bio
# 1  A POINT (18 10.5)           b
# 2  B     POINT (9 6)           c
# 3  C     POINT (4 2)           b
```

Comment: That actually doesn't work, the result should've been in the same order a,b,c. I'm not familiar with the sf library though so I'm not quite sure what could've gone wrong

Comment: plot the points on a map and  you will be surprised..